# How to bind item in ngFor to other html node without cover tag?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-directives, ngfor, angular-forms

I'm having a problem with angular 6, that I want to pass each item in ngFor to other html node without cover tag, here is my code

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of A">
....
</tr>

<tr *ngFor="let b of a">
....
</tr>
```

Do we have any solution for that ?

Comment: the second loop would need to be inside the first, a is not in any scope outside of the top ngFor. Can you provide an example of the data and what the html should look like when rendered

Comment: a real code example would be useful

Comment: Thank all you guys, I have solved my problem, I the question I dont want to put both loop under a cover tag just because it's maybe break css from design team. But I found <ng-container> tag can cover them (like React.Fragment) without any change about html node or css